# Change the FOS users connection property

Tags: symfony, jwt, fosuserbundle

I have a problem with the connection with the friends of symfony and jwt bundle, by default it uses the username to connect only I need to use email.

I first try to change the property in secutiy.yaml but I can't get it to work.

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        entity_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern:  ^/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        register:
            pattern:  ^/register
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true

        api:
            pattern:  ^/api
            stateless: true
            anonymous: false
            provider: entity_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Always when I try to connect it asks me for the username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
fos_userbundle:
    id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
```